# create query string in anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I have an anchor tag in my .aspx page. I want to add a query string to pass the employee ID of the page. I am able to pass the value but it appends a # after the value. Is there a way to remove the # or another way to pass the value?

My code:

```
 <a class="jt" href="#" rel='WorkExp.aspx?Emplid=<%# Request.QueryString["Emplid"] %>'>
         Previous Work Experience</a></th>
```

When the page is run, I receive WorkExp.aspx?emplid=111111#

I want to remove the # after the employee id.

Thanks,

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a main page which passes the Emplid in the query string to the page which has an anchor tag. In this page, I want to get the employee ID passed through the query string from the main page.Hence, when I try Request.QueryString, it retrieves the ID but appends a #. I want to remove this hash variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a class="jt" href='WorkExp.aspx?Emplid=<%= Request.QueryString["Emplid"] %>'>Previous Work Experience</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I used this example, in my 'rel' attribute in the anchor tag. I removed the # after <%.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  After a quick test, you could just remove the rel part of the element and set the href as I suggested before:

```
<a class="jt" href='WorkExp.aspx?Emplid=<%= Request.QueryString["Emplid"] %>'>Previous Work Experience</a>
```

If the # still appears at the end, all I can think of is that you are appending this to QueryString somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Kev. It didn't work. When I add the href value, it doesn't append the emplid.

Comment: Thanks Kev. I did this and it worked:

Removed the # after <%.

<a class="jt" href='WorkExp.aspx?Emplid=<%= Request.QueryString["Emplid"] %>' rel='WorkExp.aspx?Emplid=<%= Request.QueryString["Emplid"] %>'>Previous Work Experience</a>